# How to calculate the size of a HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, json

Say I have a HttpRequestMessage object built like this:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uploadUrl)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent(myObject, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
};
```

Which I will send like so:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Is there a way to calculate the size (in bytes) of the request payload before POSTing it? The reason I ask, is because I will be submitting this request to a 3rd party API and I know the API will reject my request if it exceeds a pre-determined max size. I figured if I could calculate the size of the payload in the request I could avoid posting requests that exceed this max size.

Answer (score 5):

I use :

```
requestMessage.Headers.ToString().Length +                  // Header Length
    (requestMessage.Content?.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0);   // Content Length
```

You can also read content data and calculate size of it :

```
public async Task<long> GetRequestSizeAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
{
    var reader = requestMessage.Headers.ToString();
    var content = await requestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return reader.Length + content.Length;
}
```

Sync version:

```
public long GetRequestSize(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
{
    var reader = requestMessage.Headers.ToString();
    var content = requestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return reader.Length + content.Length;
}
```

Comment: For the size of the whole request, this is at best an approximation. For example, it doesn't include the request line, the content headers, or the empty line separating header and body.